# How to find the matrix representation of a given many-qubit Hamiltonian?

Tags: matrix-representation, linear-algebra

I have the following Hamiltonian

```
H = - Z1Z2 - Z2Z3 - Z1Z3 - 6(Z1 + Z2 + Z3)
```

Here, Z1, Z2, Z3 represent the Pauli-Z operators acting on qubits 1, 2, and 3, respectively. The interaction terms Z1Z2, Z2Z3, and Z1Z3 indicate that there is a ferromagnetic coupling between adjacent qubits. How can I simplify this further by substituting for Z1Z2, Z2Z3, Z1Z3 etc. in tensor product form in computational basis? Something like this (not sure how this can be obtained)

```
Z1Z2 = (Z ⊗ Z) (|1⟩⟨1| ⊗ |0⟩⟨0| + |0⟩⟨0| ⊗ |1⟩⟨1|)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your ultimate aim is to be able to write out the 8x8 matrix for H? First, notice that all the operators are diagonal, so H must be diagonal as well. Now, let $x$ be a bit string of length 3. The non-zero elements of $H$ are
$$
\sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^3}\langle x|H|x\rangle\  |x\rangle\langle x|
$$
Moreover, your Hamiltonian is permutation invariant - it doesn't matter if I swap the qubits, the Hamiltonian remains the same. That means that $\langle x|H|x\rangle$ only depends on the weight of the bit string. So, we only need to perform 4 calculations.
$$
\langle 000|H|000\rangle=-21
$$
(all the terms give $+1$). Similarly
\begin{align*}
\langle 001|H|001\rangle&=2-1-12+6=-5 \\
\langle 011|H|011\rangle&=2-1-6+12=7 \\
\langle 111|H|111\rangle&=15 \\
\end{align*}
So, your $H$ is diagonal, with diagonal elements $(-21,-5,-5,7,-5,7,7,15)$.

Comment: thanks! how ⟨000|H|000⟩ is -21? how to compute that?

Comment: Z_iZ_j gives +1 if qubits i and j are in the same basis state and -1 if not. So those 3 terms give you a total of -3. Z_i gives +1 if qubit i is in $|0\rangle$ and -1 otherwise. So those 3 terms each give -6.